# Monolog JsonFormatter is not formatting my code?

Tags: php, monolog

I've read a lots of questions here and read some documentation. But Still don't understand how to format a JSON value with monolog.

Here my code that is not working:

`php
$formatter = new JsonFormatter();
$log->addInfo($formatter->format(['foo' => 'bar']));`

The output is always in one line instead of in a formatted way.

`bash
[2016-03-02 07:45:57] parameters.INFO: {"foo":"bar"}  [] []`

Answer (score 7):

The JsonFormatter is meant to be used for formatting the output.

```
$log = new \Monolog\Logger( 'my_log' );
$stream_handler = new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler( 'my_log_file.log' );
$stream_handler->setFormatter( new \Monolog\Formatter\JsonFormatter() );
$log->pushHandler( $stream_handler );

$log->addError( 'foo' );
```

Without the JsonFormatter you get the normal output:

```
[2016-04-04 16:37:55] my_log.ERROR: foo [] []
```

With the JsonFormatter you get JSON output:

```
{"message":"foo","context":[],"level":400,"level_name":"ERROR","channel":"my_log","datetime":{"date":"2016-04-04 16:38:14.102258","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},"extra":[]}
```

Comment: I get an error: Call to undefined method Monolog\Logger::setFormatter()

Comment: Please check the example code again. You should set the formatter on a stream handler, then add that handler to the logger. The logger itself does not use formatters.